# AWS CLI command list for checking limits?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-cli

I'm working on a project where a single section of our deployment pipeline can easily take up to an hour to deploy onto AWS. We have about 30 steps in our pipeline and one of the primary time killers of spinning up a new environment is hitting a random limit in AWS. I've searched their website for checking limits and have found a few select commands for specific environments, but are there commands (and if so, a list of them) that can check for each limit such as 'NatGatewayLimitExceeded' for example? It would be great if I could make a script that checked all of our limits before we wasted time spinning up half an instance to be blocked by something like this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you considered contacting AWS to have the limits raised or removed?

Comment: Having limits is a good thing, and they aren't the problem. We raise them all the time. Its that I'd like to check to see if our next deployment step would attempt to exceed a limit before it runs for 45 minutes and breaks because a limit was reached. If it breaks, i want to make it break at the beginning so it doesn't need to roll back and waste time.

Comment: Good point. I did not think of it that way. This open source project might help: http://awslimitchecker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: This will definitely be nice for reference, thank you. Though I was hoping for native awscli commands.

Comment: AWS provides an amazing amount of information to developers. Sometimes the obvious is overlooked. Based upon my experience AWS does pay attention to the market needs. Try opening a support ticket to see if something is in beta.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://gist.github.com/sebsto/468670c7c0d5feeade69) they say that if you have AWS Premium Support, you can do this:

```
CHECK_ID=$(aws --region us-east-1 support describe-trusted-advisor-checks \
  --language en --query 'checks[?name==`Service Limits`].{id:id}[0].id' \
  --output text)
aws support describe-trusted-advisor-check-result --check-id "$CHECK_ID" \
  --query 'result.sort_by(flaggedResources[?status!="ok"],&metadata[2])[].metadata' \
  --output table --region us-east-1
```

If you do not have AWS Premium Support, I hacked together this:

```
awscommands=($(COMP_LINE='aws' aws_completer))
for command in "${awscommands[@]}"; do COMP_LINE="aws $command" \
  aws_completer | xargs -n1 -I% printf "aws $command %\n"; done | grep limit | \
  bash 2>/dev/null
```

This uses AWS's own bash completion program to find all possible aws commands (mutatis mutandis for your environment), and then all subcommands of those commands that have "limit" in their name, and then runs them. Some of those "limit" subcommands have required options; my trick does not account for those and they just error out, so I redirected stderr to /dev/null. Therefore the results are incomplete. Suggestions for improvement are welcome.